# How to use user defined variable inside of `IF` expression?

Tags: mysql, sql

Some of my SQL statement like this:

```
  IF(timediff(a.wo_finish_time,
               IF(a.wo_failure_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                  a.wo_failure_time,
                  a.wo_creation_time)) < 0,
      0,
      timediff(a.wo_finish_time,
               IF(a.wo_failure_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                  a.wo_failure_time,
                  a.wo_creation_time)))
```

As you can see, it is verbose because part of it appears twice. So I tried user defined variable like this:

```
 if(@down_time := timediff(a.wo_finish_time,
                             IF(a.wo_failure_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                a.wo_failure_time,
                                a.wo_creation_time)) < 0,
      0,
      @down_time)
```

Maybe due to the difference in variable scope, it doesn't work. I know I can put this @down_time variable declaration in `SELECT` list, but that would also add it to the output column. I guess there must be a better way, so I post this question, hoping to find a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following `GREATEST` trick:

```
SELECT GREATEST(0, TIMEDIFF(a.wo_finish_time,
                       IF(a.wo_failure_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                       a.wo_failure_time,
                       a.wo_creation_time)))
FROM yourTable
```

Another workaround not requiring dynamic SQL would be to wrap your current query and then subquery out the correct value, something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.col < 0 THEN 0 ELSE t.col END AS col
FROM
(
    SELECT TIMEDIFF(a.wo_finish_time,
           IF(a.wo_failure_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
              a.wo_failure_time,
              a.wo_creation_time)) AS col
           -- other columns?
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

If you were already using such a subquery or performance were not critical, then this second option might make sense.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know `GREATEST()` function. Although the intention is not so obvious as `IF()`, it is a clever trick.